# QGIS 2.6 Diagram Overlay plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm not able to find the "Diagram Overlay" plugin in QGIS 2.6 (OS X) from the Manage plugin list.

Could anyone help me to download it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can activate the diagram overlay for a vector layer in layer properties > diagrams:

[image]

As a core plugin it is included in QGIS. You can find more information here: [How to draw bar diagrams on the map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66393/how-to-draw-bar-diagrams-on-the-map/66397#66397)